# Using the Avant Garde BK BT Font on Webpages?

Tags: css, google-chrome, web, fonts

If I download and use this font on my web page, will it be able to render correctly on all browsers? I have checked on Google Chrome and it is not on the list of default fonts installed.

If not, is there an alternative that can be used so my web page will be able to render properly on all the browsers and operating systems?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a web-font in order to ensure your page renders the same on all browsers. A good repository of web-fonts can be found here:

http://www.google.com/fonts/

https://edgewebfonts.adobe.com/

If you own a licence which permits you to use the font on a website, you can use the following converter to change your font into a web format

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

An example of including and using a web-font :

`HTML`

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

`CSS`

```
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```